# .NET Chart Box Plot Bleeding outside chart area

Tags: asp.net, charts, mschart

I see that when a Box crosses max and min limit on the Y-axis the box bleeds outside the chart area. Is there a solution/Tweak for this?[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I am having this problem too. A solution, while hacky, would be to alter the boxplot values to be no lower than the minimum.  Setting the lower box and lower whisker to be no lower than 50 in this example.  This could cause other problems if you show tooltips of the boxplot boundaries, so just be mindful of what else in your chart this might affect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the Min and Max values yourself or letting the control decide? Try setting them to auto.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = double.NaN;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = double.NaN;
```

Comment: I am setting Min and Max values. And when I set Min/Max and the quartile values cross the boundary then I see this overlay.

Comment: I am setting Max/Min to take y-axis to the required level. So setting auto will draw a chart boxes inside chart area. No issues. But I am looking for a solution where I can set the Max/Min y-axis to appropriate level and boxes don't jump out. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Well the Min/Max values that you are setting is sufficient if you only draw the line, but not for the boxes. So if you want to set the Min/Max values yourself you would have to take into account the possible height of the boxes as well and then readjust the Min/Max values. This can only be deduced from the data that you are using as source for the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Ed. But this solution did Not help to crop Boxes inside chart area.